# Search sequence of bytes only in heap blocks

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, windbg

I'm looking for a WinDbg tool / script which can help me search sequence of bytes in only Heap blocks.

For 32 Bit process I can use following command to search bytes by searching through entire user mode process space, but for 64 bit process it takes a lot of time

```
 s 0 L?0x7fffffff 41 42 43 44 45 46
```

Comment: Which heap? C++ heap?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the C++ heaps. There we have the `!heap` command which can help figuring out which heap addresses there are. With another `!heap <address>` it's possible to get the length of that heap. This information can then be fed into `s` to limit the address range.

While it might be possible with WinDbg scripts and `.foreach` or similar, writing WinDbg scripts is not really fun and they break easily, so let's start with a real programing language.

With this information given, let's start a [PyKd](https://pykd.codeplex.com/) script which can search through those heaps. Because I'm still not too familiar with PyKd, I'll mostly use [`dbgCommand()`](https://pykd.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PYKD%200.3.%20API%20Reference&referringTitle=Documentation#dbgCommand) and I'll use the Python part for parsing the results so that I don't have to rely on a word by word identical output.

Unfortunately my PyKd setup got broken during while writing this answer. Here's what I had before it now crashes my WinDbg. Note that this is incomplete because it does not take the search bytes as arguments yet. Add them where XXX is.

```
from pykd import *

heap = dbgCommand("!heap").split('\n')
for ntheap in heap:
    if "NT Heap" in ntheap:
        address = ntheap[0:ntheap.index("NT Heap")-1]
        heapdetails = dbgCommand("!heap "+address.strip()).split('\n')
        for detail in heapdetails:
            if "Segment at" in detail:
                end = detail[detail.index(" to ")+4:detail.index(" (")-1]
                length = hex(int(end,16)-int(address,16))
                results = dbgCommand("s "+address+" L?"+length+" XXX")
                print(results)
```

Comment: pls, upload a crash dump

Comment: @ussrhero: I tried to get one, but it just terminates the process without any exception. I already debugged WinDbg to find out what's happening

Comment: What is a version of python ? There is a similar bug with python 2.7.11